# what does the <hr /> tag do in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, tags

I saw that using `<hr />` before and after some content sort of lifts the content. Could anybody share what does the tag do and does it come/have antecedent from HTML 4.0 or is a tag done/manufactured by WordPress itself.

Example below -

```
some text 
<hr />

<h3>tax which I need to highlight/breakaway <h3>

<hr />

&nbsp;
```

now I know that `&nbsp;` is for an empty line so that there is some space, while `h3` is for headline 3 which makes text stand out a bit, do not get really what `<hr />` actually does, can somebody explain?

Any links which also explain the above would also be good.

Comment: There is no closing slash for the <hr> tag except in XHTML which you aren't using.

Comment: but in wordpress it works, doesn't seem to have an issue with it.

Comment: Doesn't change anything I said. <hr /> is not necessary in HTML.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not for an empty line. It is a non-breaking space. It is designed to be used in place of a regular space between two works which should be kept together (i.e. not placed in separate lines by word wrapping): `John&nbsp;Smith`. If you want an "empty line" then you should be using a CSS margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hr tag is used to insert a horizontal line (aka "horizontal rule"). Depending on the styling of the hr tag via CSS, it can look many different ways.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Answer (score 2):

See [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element):

> The hr element represents a paragraph-level thematic break, e.g. a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book.

As such, it makes no sense to wrap a heading in a pair of them. That is something for which CSS borders would be more suitable.

e.g.

```
h3 {
    border-top: solid black 2px;
    border-bottom: solid black 2px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

---

> does it come/have antecedent from HTML 4.0

It originally appeared in [HTML 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-5.9).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure code is correct, you should validate it at validator.w3c.org.

This code doesn't validate well:

```
<hr />

<h3>tax which I need to highlight/breakaway <h3>

<hr />

&nbsp;
```

I then chose to validate your code as an HTML fragment and one of the errors out of 4 that I see is:

> NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES
>
> ---
>
> For the current document, the validator interprets strings like  according to legacy rules that break the expectations of most authors and thus cause confusing warnings and error messages from the validator. This interpretation is triggered by HTML 4 documents or other SGML-based HTML documents. To avoid the messages, simply remove the "/" character in such contexts. NB: If you expect  to be interpreted as an XML-compatible "self-closing" tag, then you need to use XHTML or HTML5.
>
> This warning and related errors may also be caused by an unquoted attribute value containing one or more "/". Example: http://w3c.org>W3C. In such cases, the solution is to put quotation marks around the value.

It also detected that you forgot to close your `<h3>` tag. The right-most `<h3>` should be `</h3>`

Also, `<hr />` should be changed to `<hr>` which stands for horizontal rule (which is a line going across your screen).

These tags are HTML tags. If there are tags in Wordpress (maybe something like `<wordpress configuration=set>`), then they would be tags that wouldn't be used in an HTML document that a browser directly processes. They might be used as HTML comments instead. For example:

```
<div>
<p>
This is text inside html. 
<!-- <wordpress configuration=set> -->
There is other text here inside html.
</p>
</div>
```

Here's a reference of standard HTML tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/

Comment: "This code doesn't validate well" — It's perfectly valid if you use the current version of HTML (i.e. HTML 5), which I believe WordPress does by default (at least the TwentyTen theme is HTML 5). (It is wrong to to put a horizontal rule immediately after a heading though, the element *represents a paragraph-level thematic break, e.g. a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book* and it makes no sense to start section with a heading and then a theme break before you've said anything under the heading).

Comment: The OP mentioned HTML 4.0 and wordpress in his question so I assumed he was trying to understand HTML 4.0